# How to combine a list of files, which is broken while being stashed?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm working with Git Extensions.

I wanted to stash some files, but while this was being done, I interrupted that process and now I have some files being stashed (in `stash@{0}`) and some in my "Commit".

I would like to combine all those files together without committing them.

If I simply stash them, just another stash will be created.
If I try to drop the stash, this is refused because of the presence of files in the "Commit".

I see two solutions:

- Find a way to add the list of files in the "Commit" to the current stash (like an "amend commit, but for a stash).
- Find a way to copy all files in the "Commit" to another temporary directory, empty the "Commit", drop the stashed files and copy back from the remote directory.

Does anybody have an idea on how to perform one of the mentioned actions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I admit, it's not nice:

The "commit" list of Git-Extensions has the possibility to copy the full path of every file (this can be done all together). I copied every file using `xcopy` (`/T`, `/E`, ...) to a temporary directory, emptied the "commit" list, then I could pop the stash and copy all files from that temporary directory again.